# How to Transform view in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

How to transform UIView in Clockwise, Anticlockwise, Flip, and Flop using Objective-C?

for Flip :-

```
    tempLayerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
```

for Flop :-

```
    tempLayerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, -1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To transform view clockwise / Anti-clockwise use or you can set degree in

```
tempLayerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

tempLayerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI);
```